# Send a mouse click via windows Batch file when a certain key is pressed

Tags: windows, batch, mouse

When a certain key pressed from my physical keyboard (for instance: Ctrl key) i want to send a mouse click to an application running on windows 10 via a windows batch file.

To breakdown the above statement,
"control key" pressed: send a mouse left click to an application that is already running in windows 10 (or to send the mouse click to any active window which is currently in focus)

Do it in a loop until I exit the windows batch file.

Comment: This sounds like a bunch of bad idea all wrapped up in one.  [This](https://www.murgee.com/mouse-click/) is what you are probably asking for.  Doing this from a REAL LANGUAGE is a bad idea.  This is even worse.  Professional testers fail at this every day.. and they would never try to do it from a batch file.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, I have checked these third party tools which are offering mouse click options. I was wondering if it was possible via a batch file or not. So, from your comment, i am assuming that its not doable?
Or it is doable but not consistent?
Can you at least write me a short piece of script which will check for button press and send a mouse click?
I will connect the dots and do the rest. Just a "check for button press" piece of code and then "send a mouse click" piece of code.

Comment: Fair enough.. yes doable even if I think it is a bad idea. ;) .. No, I will not write code for this.. but you might check out that link I provided.  Good luck Ahsan, I was grumpy last night and I am sorry.  I hope you get this solved.

Comment: Thanks @SeñorCMasMas.